# How to get headers of the response from fetch

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I am using fetch on chrome Version 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit). I want to get all the headers in the response. Following snippet only return `content-type` but if you peek into chrome dev tools it shows many other response headers. How to get other headers from fetch.

```
  fetch('https://httpbin.org/get')
    .then(response => {
       const headers = response.headers.entries();
       let header = headers.next();
       while (!header.done){
         console.log(headers.value);
         header = header.next();
       }
    })
```

I tried polyfilling(manually overriding) the github implementation. Still no luck.

Comment: If you know what header you are looking for you could try response.headers.get('header-name')

Comment: Looking at the compatibility table at the bottom of this page it doesn't say that chrome supports entries() yet. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can't access all the headers when requesting cross-domain content via ajax. You can access all headers if origin is same.

As explained in W3 Specifications [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#terminology), only `Content-Type`, `Last-modified`, `Content-Language`, `Cache-Control`, `Expires`, `Pragma` headers are accessible.

Further `https://httpbin.org/get` send only `Content-Type` header from list of accessible headers so, you got that only.

Edit: You can expose non-standard CORS response headers by sending [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) with the headers you want the client to access on the response.

Comment: This was super helpful. For those Rails 5 developers, editing `config/initializers/cors.rb` worked. I added: `expose: ['Location'],` to the `resource '*'` statement

Comment: Add your custom header for the Access-Control-Expose-Headers on the  server, to allow the browser to get custom headers on CORS.
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'my-custom-header');