# how to access response headers in React from Rails api-pagination gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, pagination, will-paginate

So I got this gem to work in limiting the amounts returned in the JSON response. However I'm not sure how to access the links in the headers that let you get to the next and previous pages.
Here is my controller:

```
def index
    movies = Movie.all
    paginate json: movies, per_page: 50
end
```

This is the part of the readme for the gem that says you can access next and prev through the headers:

```
$ curl --include 'https://localhost:3000/movies?page=5'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Link: <http://localhost:3000/movies?page=1>; rel="first",
  <http://localhost:3000/movies?page=173>; rel="last",
  <http://localhost:3000/movies?page=6>; rel="next",
  <http://localhost:3000/movies?page=4>; rel="prev"
Total: 4321
Per-Page: 10
# ...
```

I can see them in Postman, but have yet to find a way to access them in my React front end. Thank you for any help you're able to offer.
This is the url for the gem: [api-pagination gem](https://github.com/davidcelis/api-pagination)

Comment: This is nothing to do with react; just do it as you'd with any js code. also for rest APIs why are your putting so much relevant data in headers instead of the response JSON??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.headers.get('Link')` solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Are you accessing this data in React through a fetch request? Something like

```
fetch('url').then(res => {res.json()})
```

You should be able to access headers with `fetch('url').then(res => res.headers)`. You can then manipulate them or save them to state or whatever you want to do with them. Fetch API docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers).

Comment: Ya that's how I'm accessing the data in React. I tried that and they're just an empty object.

Comment: You're getting the correct body back though? Is accessing the links through headers really necessary? I'm assuming you could just hit `/movies?page2` directly if you're on page1.

Comment: Also, if you open inspector tools and look at the response in the network tab, you should see that response. Does it have the headers there?

Comment: Ya I'm able to get the data for the first page. Oh sweet they're there. How would one access those tho?

Comment: Hm, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953864/how-to-get-headers-of-the-response-from-fetch). It may have something to do with the CORS from the Rails back end.

Comment: Ya I found that too. :(  I put `expose: ['Link']` in the cors.rb and `'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': ['Link'],` in my application.rb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163830/discussion-between-mike-heft-and-shirley).

Answer (score 2):

Actually it worked to me. if anyone come here by searching.
Add **expose: ['header-key']** in cors configuration in your rails app.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
  
      resource '*',
        headers: :any,
        methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head], expose: ['X-Pagination']
    end
end
```

After adding expose, you'll be able to get the header key in your client-side code by using response.headers.get("X-Pagination").

Note:- I verified it by using fetch API call resonse.

Answer (score 1):

What I did with in a similar situation was to add the following in my rails controller:

response.header['my_attribute_name'] = my_value
headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'my_attribute_name'

Then on the front-end I just used:

response.headers.get("my_attribute_name")

This solved my issue.

Comment: Nice. I'll give that a try next time. But this problem was with my understanding of how to use React with this gem https://github.com/davidcelis/api-pagination

Answer (score 0):

This is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) restriction.

White list headers (by implementing [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) in the server) that you are using for pagination.

Only then you can access any header on a CORS request.

Please also note that, this restriction does not apply on requests from the same origin.