# Unable to receive authorization headers in express backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am making an MERN app. Inside useEffect I am making a API Call in which I am setting a autorizarion token. But I am unable to get authorization token from headers in the backend.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(`${API}/${userId}/courses`,{
        method:"GET",
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }).then(response=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then(data=>{
        console.log(data)
    })

})
```

If I try to console.log `req.headers` in backend I am getting response as:

```
{ host: 'localhost:3030',
  connection: 'keep-alive'
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
}
```

There is no authorization property in it.
But if I try to make same api call from POSTMAN I am getting authorization token in headers. What's the problem?

Comment: I believe, you run site on different domain than server. That is why you have not access to non standard headers (cross origin resource sharing).
Please, look at this detailed answer for clarification https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953864/how-to-get-headers-of-the-response-from-fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the headers to key `headers` in arguments Object.

```
fetch('${API}/${userId}/courses',{
        method:"GET",
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
```